# Castle Windsor: How to release instance with PerThread lifestyle

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

i'm using Castle Windsor with PerThread lifestyle in a windows service.

When a new thread worker is started, a new instance is created by windsor, but never disposed and stays in memory for the entire life-cycle of our win-service.

I've seen in the Windsor documentation that:

> Releasing the component explicitly **does** **nothing**. Instances will be
>   released when the **container** they're registered with is **disposed**

But in our case - i need to release a PerThread instance at the end of the thread work. Therefore we cannot dispose the entire container - which will dispose all the needed instances of other threads or any resolved instances at all. 

A solution which will require disposing a child containers etc - seems to be too complex and not really effective for our per-thread need.

For now we **really concern** about the amount of instances that will be hold in the IOC container till the windows service will be stopped.

**Questions:**

1. Is there a way to achieve this action - to release the specific per-thread instance from the IOC container in order that it will be disposed by the GC?


2. Is there a preferred way to solve this issue by a custom lifestyle or something similar to this?


3. I've read about a way that may be right for our case - using "**Scoped**" lifestyle and calling "`Container.BeginScope()`" at the beginning of the thread worker, and dispose the scope at the end of the thread's work.

 But i'm not familiar with this lifestyle and if its thread-safe and won't cause any problems using this option in a thread context.

TNX.

**Update 1:**
Here's a basic example which reflects our case flow.

```
 // This is a thread worker logic.
// We need that IConfig will be the same instance for the entire thread's context.
public void ThreadWorker(object manager)
{
    // Init config object.
    var config = Container.Resolve<IConfig>();
    // Updating states in config
    config.init(manager);

    // working.
    doSomeLogics(manager.services);
}

private void doSomeLogics(List<IService> services) 
{
    foreach (Iservice curService in services) 
    {
        curService.Execute();
    }
}
```

```
// Each IService implementor comes from external dlls and cannot be changed since its decoupled from our main app.

public class Service1 : IService 
{
    public void Execute()
    {
        // Use the IConfig instance which need to be the same instance per thread.
        IConfig curConfig = Container.Resolve<IConfig>();

        // using the curConfig properties to do a specific work...
    }
}

public class Service2 : IService 
{
    public void Execute()
    {
        // Use the IConfig instance which need to be the same instance per thread.
        IConfig curConfig = Container.Resolve<IConfig>();

        // using the curConfig properties to do a specific work...
    }
}
```

Comment: That quote applies to Singletons, not PerThread components. Whereever you Resolve you should Release.

Comment: Hi phil - i've taken this quote from here: https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/lifestyles.md at the "PerThread" section. The main problem is that the thread instance is not released even if i'm calling container.ReleaseCompnent directly.

Comment: So if you're in control of thread beginning and ending work why not just register as transient, resolve at commencement of thread work and release at end?

Comment: The reason is that we use external services which are used inside our thread scope - where they also access IOC to resolve instances. This external services are decoupled from our main thread's context which is why we can't pass them any (transient) instance. This is why we need to define that each IOC access inside our thread scope will resolve the same instances. If we'll use Transient, any IOC call inside this external services (external dlls) will create a new instance and won't use the same one.

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: Yup..i've added a code example to my post.

Comment: Does the implementation of IConfig also implement IDisposable?